# Helm ingress-nginx on China region

Tags: kubernetes-helm, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to install Ingress-Nginx on China region kuber (use  helm install
[name] ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx command)
I can install 3.0.0 all versions, but can't install 4.0.0... i got an error "Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: failed pre-install: timed out waiting for the condition"

According to the logs from kuber helm can't find correct image: 'Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "registry.k8s.io/ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen@sha256:64d8c73dca9"

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: It looks like there is no `4.0.0`version for that chart https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx -- can you try `4.0.1`?

Comment: yes, i tried different versions of 4.0..., maybe problem with repo, which i use, but i used it in Europe region to install nginx version 4.0.18 and i didn't have any problems

Answer (score 1):

According to official support we can install version 4 with more specific command:
helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \

--version 4.0.13 \

--namespace ingress-basic --create-namespace \

--set controller.replicaCount=1 \

--set controller.nodeSelector."kubernetes.io/os"=linux \

--set controller.image.registry=k8sgcr.azk8s.cn \

--set controller.image.image=ingress-nginx/controller \

--set controller.image.tag=v1.0.4 \

--set controller.image.digest="" \

--set controller.image.repository=k8sgcr.azk8s.cn/ingress-nginx/controller \

--set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.nodeSelector."kubernetes.io/os"=linux \

--set controller.service.annotations."service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-health-probe-request-path"=/healthz \

--set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.image.registry=k8sgcr.azk8s.cn \

--set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.image.image=ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen \

--set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.image.tag=v1.1.1 \

--set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.image.digest="" \

--set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."kubernetes.io/os"=linux \

--set defaultBackend.image.registry=k8sgcr.azk8s.cn \

--set defaultBackend.image.image=defaultbackend-amd64 \

--set defaultBackend.image.tag=1.5 \

--set defaultBackend.image.repository=k8sgcr.azk8s.cn/defaultbackend-amd64